# JBOSS AS 7.1 JBAS014775: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jboss

My application connects to a postgresql database, but when I start my jboss a

> JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>
> service jboss.jdbc-driver.postgresql-9_4_1208_jre7_jar (missing)
>   dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/postgresDS]

How do I fix this? and when I continue with my application despite the missing dependencies, I got a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver exception

I have been searching for a solution for hours but I can't still fix the issue.

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/postgresDS" pool-name="postgresDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>test</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <background-validation-millis>0</background-validation-millis>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar" module="org.postgresql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

module/xml on my /jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/org/postgresql/main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0" name="org.postgresql">  
<resources>  
    <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar"/>  
</resources>  
<dependencies>  
    <module name="javax.api"/>  
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
</dependencies>  
</module>
```

I'm using servlets, jsp and jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a jboss-dependencies,xml file with a module dependency on the org.postgresql module. You can also do this with a MANIFEST.MF. Both files are placed in the WAR's META-INF dir.